# Finding the center of the diameter of a graphtree using BFS?

Tags: graph, breadth-first-search

So this function, biggest_dist, finds the diameter of a graph(the given graph in the task is **always** a tree).

What I want it instead to find is to find the center of the diameter, the node with the least maximum distance to all the other nodes.

I "kinda" understand the idea that we can do this by finding the path from `u` to `t` (distance between `u`and `t`is the diameter) by keeping track of the parent for each node. From there I choose the node in the middle of `u`and `t`? My question is how do I implement that for this function here? Will this make it output node 2 for this graph?

```
int biggest_dist(int n, int v, const vector< vector<int> >& graph)
//n are amount of nodes, v is an arbitrary vertex
{ //This function finds the diameter of thegraph
int INF = 2 * graph.size(); // Bigger than any other length
vector<int> dist(n, INF);

dist[v] = 0;
queue<int> next;
next.push(v);

int bdist = 0; //biggest distance
while (!next.empty()) {
    int pos = next.front();
    next.pop();
    bdist = dist[pos];

    for (int i = 0; i < graph[pos].size(); ++i) {
        int nghbr = graph[pos][i];
        if (dist[nghbr] > dist[pos] + 1) {
            dist[nghbr] = dist[pos] + 1;
            next.push(nghbr);
        }
    }
}

return bdist;
}
```

Comment: For trees, there's a cute algorithm you can use: simultaneously remove all the leaves in the graph and repeat this until you're left with one or two nodes. Those remaining nodes are then the centers. Would that work for you, or do you specifically want to work with the above code?

Comment: Uhh... you could just treat it as a graph and dfs from u to t and then return diameter/2 times. Or if it's really more convenient as a tree for some reason you could root the tree, find all depths and then find the (diameter/2)th parent of the lower node... (I think?) EDIT: how does your code find the diameter of the graph, it seems to just find the furthest distance from node v?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact, this function does not compute the diameter. It computes the furthest vertex from a given vertex `v`.

To compute the diameter of a tree, you need first to choose an arbitrary vertex (let's say `v`), then find the vertex that is furthest away from `v` (let's say `w`), and then find a vertex that is furthest away from `w`, let's sat `u`. The distance between `w` and `u` is the diameter of the tree, but the distance between `v` and `w` (what your function is doing) is not guaranteed to be the diameter.

To make your function compute the diameter, you will need to make it return the vertex it found alongside with the distance. Conveniently, it will always be the last element you process, so just make your function remember the last element it processed alongside with the distance to that element, and return them both. Then call your function twice, first from any arbitrary vertex, then from the vertex that the first call returned.

To make it actually find the center, you can also remember the parent for each node during your BFS. To do so, allocate an extra array, say `prev`, and when you do

```cpp
dist[nghbr] = dist[pos] + 1;
```

also do

```cpp
prev[nghbr] = pos;
```

Then at the end of the second call to the function, you can just descend bdist/2 times into the prev, something like:

```cpp
center = lastVertex;
for (int i = 0; i + i < bdist; ++ i) center = prev[center];
```

So with a little tweaks to your function (making it return the furthest vertex from `v` and a vertex that is on the middle of that path, and not return the diameter at all), this code is likely to return you the center of the tree (I only tested it on your example, so it might have some off by one errors)

```cpp
pair<int, int> biggest_dist(int n, int v, const vector< vector<int> >& graph)
{
    int INF = 2 * graph.size(); // Bigger than any other length
    vector<int> dist(n, INF);
    vector<int> prev(n, INF);

    dist[v] = 0;
    queue<int> next;
    next.push(v);

    int bdist = 0; //biggest distance
    int lastV = v;
    while (!next.empty()) {
        int pos = next.front();
        next.pop();
        bdist = dist[pos];
        lastV = pos;

        for (int i = 0; i < graph[pos].size(); ++i) {
            int nghbr = graph[pos][i];
            if (dist[nghbr] > dist[pos] + 1) {
                dist[nghbr] = dist[pos] + 1;
                prev[nghbr] = pos;
                next.push(nghbr);
            }
        }
    }

    int center = lastV;
    for (int i = 0; i + i < bdist; ++ i) center = prev[center];

    return make_pair(lastV, center);
}

int getCenter(int n, const vector< vector<int> >& graph)
{
    // first call is to get the vertex that is furthest away from vertex 0, where 0 is just an arbitrary vertes
    pair<int, int> firstResult = biggest_dist(n, 0, graph);
    // second call is to find the vertex that is furthest away from the vertex just found
    pair<int, int> secondResult = biggest_dist(n, firstResult.first, graph);
    return secondResult.second;
}
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for! Thank you! :-)